# Running an Active Directory Primary Domain Controller as a virtual machine?

Tags: active-directory, virtualization, hyper-v

Should the Active Directory PDC always be a physical machine or would it be okay to run it in a VM? What are the implications/trade offs/gotchas?

As a corollary to this, what about running a physical PDC that is also a Hyper-V host? Any implications there (especially for guest VM's that may also be SQL or Exchange Servers?)

Note: Performance implications are secondary. My main concern is gotchas.

Comment: See http://serverfault.com/questions/15196/can-windows-domain-controller-be-virtualized

Comment: See this question:
[can-windows-domain-controller-be-virtualized](http://serverfault.com/questions/15196/can-windows-domain-controller-be-virtualized)

Comment: There are no "PDC's" in an Active Directory domain. Why does this terminology persist?

Comment: @Evan Anderson - the terminology is likely simply a function of the PDCe FSMO role which does continue to exist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're talking about the domain controller holding the PDC Emulator FSMO role I would strongly recommend running it on physical hardware. It's the master time sync source for the entire domain (and the entire forest, if in the forest root domain of a multi-domain forest). Clocks on virtual machines are notorious for drifting and time sync is pretty important since Active Directory bases authentication on Kerberos, which, in turn, has time sensitivity built-in (albeit you can configure it to be more "sloppy" if you really want to).

Comment: Thanks! Any gotchas on using the PDC (excuse me, "FSMO Role") also as a Hyper-V host?

Comment: I'm not aware of any specific issues. Microsoft's recommended best practice is to keep a Hyper-V host free from any other "Roles", but it will probably work fine.

Answer (score 1):

I tend to error on the side of caution, but I have HyperV servers running DCs all the time... The hypervisor is joined to the domain for convenience, but that is all...

Comment: In the past few years, the guidance from MS has changed and time sync has gotten better for guests in the major virtualization platforms.