# Can a Hyper-V 2008R2 Box join the domain of one of its child VMs?

Tags: windows-server-2008, active-directory, hyper-v

I'm researching deploying Hyper-V Server R2 (the stand alone product - not the Server 2008 role) into our environment and was curious how the domain joining process would work if the domain controller resided on a guest OS on the Hyper-V box itself?

Is this supported? Or does the domain controller that the Hyper-V box connects to have to be on another physical server box?

Comment: Already covered: http://serverfault.com/questions/15196/can-windows-domain-controller-be-virtualized and http://serverfault.com/questions/70514/running-an-active-directory-primary-domain-controller-as-a-virtual-machine

Comment: I searched but didn't find those. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've done this with Windows 2008 Hyper-V with two hosts and DC's running as VM's on both - I haven't tried a completely cold boot of the entire environment though, this just allows me to reliably shut down either host without losing the domain. I wouldn't recommend it though for all of the reasons outlined in the answers to the questions linked to in Graeme Donaldson's comment, keeping at least one physical DC is very strongly recommended.