# Domain Controller authentication

Tags: windows-server-2008, active-directory

The idea is to find number of users logged on to a particular logon server. We have one physical windows 2003 server and one virtual windows 2008 server as part of domain. The aim is to backup 2008 server VM during business hours.

We've thought of this: Find out all users who are authenticated to a 2008 logon server, and handle their logoffs/logons individually while server is off and being copied over. So, how to find all users who are authenticated to either server? If number of logons is high, it will be difficult to implement.

Are there any better ideas?

Comment: This is reason why you should have automatic load balancing (failover) and fixed service windows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What is it that you're trying to accomplish? Do you really need to backup this server during business hours? It would be much better to schedule this outside of working hours. Your goal as a system administrator should be to ensure that services are always available when people need to be working. I encourage you to look at backup solutions that don't require the server to be shut down at all.

It sounds like both of your servers are domain controllers, is that correct? And because you talk about the 2008 server being "off", it sounds like you're talking about making a backup by copying the VMDK file. If that's true, BE CAREFUL! This approach is risky. For more details, see the question: [Can windows domain controller be virtualized?](https://serverfault.com/questions/15196/can-windows-domain-controller-be-virtualized).

As to your actual question, it is possible to find out which users/computers have an active SMB session with your server, but I'm not sure if it's possible or easy to determine which computers are using the server as their Logon Server. You need to realize that checking either of those conditions alone doesn't give you enough information to know that the server is unused. You can be authenticated with one server and accessing files on another.

Please reconsider your approach, and look for a better way to backup your server(s).

Comment: We want to copy a DC and run it in an isolated environment along with some other servers that need a DC to communicate. By business hours I mean the live DCs cannot be stopped. Yes both 2003/2008 servers are DC. Or is there a tool that can be run on Server 2008 DC that copies all AD which we can expand on a vanilla (isolated) 2008 Server later promoted to DC with same domain name as that of live DC.